# thingsboard: system error 1067

Tags: thingsboard

Please help after installing Thingsboard successfully on windows I'm getting this error while try start the services.

```
The ThingsBoard Server Application service is starting.
The ThingsBoard Server Application service could not be started.
A system error has occurred.
System error 1067 has occurred.
The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

Comment: none of the search result helped me that's why i'm here

Comment: Do you have any logs related to this issue?

Comment: Add install.log file . I found 5-10 erros while installing xdd

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, you must set the full path to the java file.to do that:

1- open the thingsboard.xml file in the base directory.
2- search for this line `<executable>java</executable>`
3- change the above line with `<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java</executable>`
4- `net start thingsboard`

### output

```
The ThingsBoard Server Application service is starting.
The ThingsBoard Server Application service was started successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug (see [here](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/883)).

If AYR1112013's solution will not work, you can temporarly fix the issue by removing the flag "-XX:+UseCondCardMark" in your thingsboard.xml.

After that start the service as usual with "net start thingsboard".

Comment: Your solution worked for me with the recent thingsboard version. I'd add that you want to comment the line out, like that: `<!--    <startargument>-XX:+UseCondCardMark</startargument> -->`